# Update a object variable when called

Tags: python

I am learning python, For sure a stupid question but I cannot find any answer.

I have an object

```
class ant(object):

    def __init__(self, age):
        self.age = 0

    def update_age(self)
        self.age += 1

pebbles = myant(25)

#check age
print pebbles.age
```

Now what I want to do is that every time someone checks pebble.age, pebbles automatically runs update_age() internally.
Is it possible to do it? or every time I have to check pebbles_age I have to write:

```
pebbles.update_age()
print pebbles.age.
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

You could implement this using a [property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property):

```
class Ant(object):  # note leading uppercase, per style guide (PEP-8)

    def __init__(self):  # you ignore the age parameter anyway
        self._age = 0

    def update_age(self):
        self._age += 1

    @property
    def age(self):
        self.update_age()
        return self._age
```

This makes `age` read-only, and increments correctly:

```
>>> an_ant = Ant()
>>> an_ant.age
1
>>> an_ant.age
2
>>> an_ant.age = 10

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    an_ant.age = 10
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```